# Running Balance Based on Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with these attributes:

```
data = {'Date':['01/01/2022','01/02/2022','01/03/2022','01/04/2022','01/05/2022'],
        'ID': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
        'Sick': [0,0,8,0,4],
        'Grant': [80, 'nan','nan','nan', 'nan'],
        'CarryForward': [80,80,80,80,72]}

df
         Date ID        Sick   Grant  CarryForward
0  01/01/2022  1           0    80            80
1  01/02/2022  1           0   nan            80
2  01/03/2022  1           8   nan            80
3  01/04/2022  1           0   nan            80
4  01/05/2022  1           4   nan            72
```

I have sorted the data frame by date and grouped by ID. I want to add a column called "running balance" with this logic:

- if Grant is nan AND Sick is nan (or zero), running balance = CarryForward
- if Grant is nan AND Sick is NOT nan, running balance = CarryForward - Sick
- else running balance = Grant

the code I did for this is:

```
df['running_balance'] = np.where((df['Grant'].isnull()) & (df['Sick'].isnull()), df['CarryForward'], 
      np.where((df['Grant'].isnull()) & (df['Sick'].notnull()),
                df['CarryForward']- df['Sick'], 
                df['Grant']))
```

And this works to give me this result:

```
         Date ID         Sick    Grant  CarryForward  running_balance
0  01/01/2022  1           0    80            80               80
1  01/02/2022  1           0   nan            80               80
2  01/03/2022  1           8   nan            80               72
3  01/04/2022  1           0   nan            80               80
4  01/05/2022  1           4   nan            72               68
```

The problem I am running into is once there is a value in Sick, it calculates the running balance correctly, but I need that new value to be carried forward to the next row. so row index 3, the running balance value should be 72. The CarryForward value will EVENTUALLY reflect the Sick value being subtracted (as seen in row index 4, but it is at a later date, and I need an accurate running balance for each day.

This is my desired result:

```
         Date ID       Sick    Grant  CarryForward  running_balance
0  01/01/2022  1           0    80            80               80
1  01/02/2022  1           0   nan            80               80
2  01/03/2022  1           8   nan            80               72
3  01/04/2022  1           0   nan            80               72
4  01/05/2022  1           4   nan            72               68
```

Things I've tried: I tried to adjust my np.where statement to use the previous row running balance using .shift() but that does not take into account when the ID changes to a new group (yes, I tried to do .groupby also). I also tried to do a .ffill() and/or .bfill(), but that did not work, as there arent any na values.

TIA for any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Because subtracting NaN/0 doesn't change a value, you don't have to use a conditional, perform a simple subtraction:

```
df['running_balance'] = df['Grant'].fillna(df['CarryForward'].sub(df['Sick']))
```

That said, a solution with conditions (useless here) would be:

```
m1 = df['Grant'].isna()
m2 = df['Sick'].fillna(0).eq(0)
df['running_balance'] = np.select([m1&m2, m1&~m2],
                                  [df['CarryForward'],
                                   df['CarryForward'].sub(df['Sick'])],
                                  df['Grant']
                                 )
```

Output:

```
         Date ID  Sick  Grant  CarryForward  running_balance
0  01/01/2022  1     0   80.0            80             80.0
1  01/02/2022  1     0    NaN            80             80.0
2  01/03/2022  1     8    NaN            80             72.0
3  01/04/2022  1     0    NaN            80             80.0
4  01/05/2022  1     4    NaN            72             68.0
```

Comment: the running balance does not carry forward from row 2 to row 3 etc. The running balance values should be 80.0, 80.0, 72.0, 72.0, 68.0

Comment: I see, then you have to subtract `df.groupby('ID')['Sick'].cumsum()`

Comment: I'll edit the answer a bit later, I'm AFK now